# Is there a way to have Debootstrap automatically configure locales?

Tags: debootstrap, locale

I like to use Debootstrap for making sparse systems (usually a base for something embedded) or paravirtualized Xen guests.

I'm familiar with how to tell Debootstrap what packages I want beyond the typical minimal base, but I have yet to find the right combination of tools to let me specify and auto generate locales after the base system has been installed.

Do I need to do this in my own scripts, or is there a way to tell Debootstrap what locales I want and have it just generate them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using [grml-debootstrap](http://grml.org/grml-debootstrap/). This is a wrapper script around `debootstrap` and comes from the [grml](http://grml.org/) live cd. This script has a file `/etc/debootstrap/locale.gen` where you can put your locales and they are generated at the right time. `grml-debootstrap` also has lots of more advantages and its worth to look at.